# slicing Tensorflow FixedLengthRecordReader value

Tags: python, tensorflow, slice

I'm implementing a regression network mapping images to poses, using Tensorflow/python API and am trying to process the output of a FixedLengthRecordReader.

I'm trying to adapt the [cifar10 example](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/models/image/cifar10/cifar10_input.py) minimally for my purposes.

The cifar10 example reads the raw bytes, decodes, then splits.

```
result.key, value = reader.read(filename_queue)

# Convert from a string to a vector of uint8 that is record_bytes long.
record_bytes = tf.decode_raw(value, tf.uint8)

# The first bytes represent the label, which we convert from uint8->int32.
result.label = tf.cast(
    tf.slice(record_bytes, [0], [label_bytes]), tf.int32)

# The remaining bytes after the label represent the image, which we reshape
# from [depth * height * width] to [depth, height, width].
depth_major = tf.reshape(tf.slice(record_bytes, [label_bytes], [image_bytes]),
                         [result.depth, result.height, result.width])
# Convert from [depth, height, width] to [height, width, depth].
result.uint8image = tf.transpose(depth_major, [1, 2, 0])
```

I am reading from a list of binary files with data saved as (pose_data, image_data). Because my pose data is float32 and my image data is uint8, I want to slice first, then cast. Unfortunately, the value result of reader.read is a zero-dimensional string tensor, so slicing doesn't work.

```
key, value = reader.read(filename_queue)
print value.dtype
print value.get_shape()

<dtype: 'string'>
()
```

The result of tf.decode_raw(value, dtype) is a 1-dimensional array, but requires a dtype to be specified, and tf.string isn't a valid type that it takes.

Is it possible to slice before decoding? Or do I have to decode -> case back to string -> slice -> recast? Is there another way altogether?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cifar10 example mentioned by the OP as well as the solution with decode twice does not work when your data has multiple types (OP's question) and doesn't 'line up' (more general case).

If your data is for example:

```
[float32][int16][int16]
```

the twice decode works. However if it your data is:

```
[int16][float32][int16]
```

it does not work as the tf.decode_raw doesn't accept an offset of a half float32.

What does work in this case is [`tf.substr()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.2/api_docs/python/tf/substr), the return value from

```
result.key, value = reader.read(filename_queue)
```

is actually a string (or a bytestring if you will) and let itself split.

Answer (score -1):

Found a solution: decode twice and throw out half. Not that efficient (and if anyone has a better solution, I'd be glad to hear it) but it seems to work.

```
key, value = reader.read(filename_queue)
uint8_bytes = tf.decode_raw(value, tf.uint8)
uint8_data = uint8_bytes[:n_uint8_vals]
float32_bytes = tf.decode_raw(value, tf.float32)
float32_start_index = n_uint8_vals // 4
float32_data = float32_bytes[float32_start_index:]
```

This requires `n_uint8_vals` to be a factor of 4.

Comment: link is broken, I'd love to see the example if it's possible to paste here.